# C access control practices

Tags: c

I am writing a small shell as a course exercise, which emulates bash's autocompletion and history mechanisms, resulting in a main.c file for managing user commands, and a raw.c file for managing the terminal in raw mode.

It is unlikely any file in the project will ever need call anything except raw.c's get_line() method, therefore my instinct is to only include this get_line() method in raw.h, to prevent accidental access of another raw.c method and further complexities.

Where can a good primer and or discussion on C access control techniques be found, in particular whether it is a good idea to emulate OO language's private/public concepts, and how it is usually done, if so?

Comment: in my opinion, C is not an academically language to teach good concepts, but an industrial language to "get things done", whereby "things" are to be viewed in the corresponding scope. It is alway good practice to hide the implementation from the definition, but it is a lot of syntactically overhead (hard to maintain and read) to hide things with concepts not inherent to C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: "OO's private / public concepts" are **not** "access control". Even if something is "private" it's still there, and can still be accessed. You have protected it against *accidential* access, but that is a far cry from "securing" it (from an "authorization" point of view). A determined and / or malicious client can still get at it, because "security" is not what those mechanics are for.

Once you understood that, you realize that all those "visibility" things - whether you declare something in a header, or make it public vs. private, or whatever - are basically aiming at *maintainability*: Reducing the amount of identifiers in the current scope, reducing the amount of functions and variables you have to *think* about in a given context.

Then, you say that your "instinct is to only include this get_line() method in raw.h". You realize that this is faulty wording? You can *declare* that function in a header file, you can *include* that header file, but you don't *include* a *function*.

So. You implement functions that belong together in a translation unit (main.c, raw.c). You *declare* functions that might be called from *outside* that translation unit in that translation unit's header file (raw.h). All functions *not* to be called from the outside, you define as `static` inside the translation unit itself, and don't declare them in a header at all.

As for emulating another language's concepts, don't. Do things the way they are done in the language you are currently using, or use a different language.

Comment: Thank you, I meant visibility, not access control. Thanks for your last paragraph, that is also what I wanted to know, and lastly, I *include* text in a text file, even if it is a .h ;)

Comment: @pouzzler: I understand where you're coming from, but every language has its own glossary. If you say "declaring" instead of "including", your intent will be clearer to any C coder who's listening.

Comment: I was kidding, thanks for the explanations again!

Comment: +1 very nicely written.

Answer (score 1):

Private functions in `raw.c` should of course be declared `static` (and omitted from the public header). Then they're only visible and callable from the same "compilation unit", i.e. from within `raw.c`.

Answer (score 1):

Only public method should be put into the `.h`

Private method must be declared `static` at the top of the `.c` file.

If your module is using multi `.c` files, you should not put the function into the public `.h`. Instead you should create a second private `.h`, for example : `mymodule_p.h` instead of `mymodule.h`.  It is like a protected function